# Oversampling with Epsilon

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification

I have a question about data mining. I have a dataset of 74 instances that belong to 4 classes. As the number of each class is not enough to obtain a good accuracy using some classifiers( svm, rna, knn) I need to "oversampling" the number of instances of each class.

I have heard that there is a method to do this. It consists in generating these new instances as follows:

```
new_instance <---- original_instance + u(epsilon)
```

but I haven't got more knowledge about it.

Anybody has used this method to "oversampling" his data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never used this oversampling method, but I think you can find useful pointers [in this paper](http://www3.nd.edu/~dial/papers/SPRINGER05.pdf).

Several oversampling as well as undersampling are described. It should help you find the more suitable method for your case.